# Ao lidar com delete/update, devo fazer o unsubscribe no modo Async Pipe?

Tags: angular

Eu sou novato em Angular.

Um dos principais objetivos do async pipe é automaticamente cuidar de se inscrever (subscribe) e cancelar sua inscrição (unsubscribe).

Tenho duas dúvidas:

**Primeira Dúvida**

Ao lidar com delete ou update  (ambos são API services), Preciso cancelar a inscrição via ngOnDestroy?

```
projects$: Observable<Project[]>;

constructor(
    private projectService: ProjectService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.loadProject();
}   


loadProject(){
    this.projects$ = this.projectService.getProjects()
    .pipe(
        map(result => {
            if(result.success){
                return result.data;
            }
        })
    );
}


deleteProject(){
    if(this.projectToDelete){
        const id = this.projectToDelete.id;
        this.projectService.deleteProject(id).subscribe(result => {
            if(result.success){
                this.loadProject();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Segunda Dúvida**

Existe uma outra maneira de deletar um elemento especifico de um `Observable` sem chamar a API que carrega o `projects$`? Algo abaixo, diferente com o código de cima:

```
    //Neste caso  this.projectsects type não é um observable.
    deleteProject(){
        if(this.projectToDelete){
            const id = this.projectToDelete.id;
            this.projectService.deleteProject(id)
            .subscribe(result => {
                if(result.success){
                    this.projects = this.projects.filter(item => {
                        return item.id != id;
                    });
                    this.projectToDelete = null;
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Da [documentação](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) do Angular:

*"The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. **When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically** to avoid potential memory leaks."*

O Async Pipe irá fazer tanto o *subscribe* como o *unsubscribe* automaticamente quando o componente é iniciado e destruido

Você deve filtrar o array dentro da função `map` para alterar o valor de um *Observable*:

```
this.projects$ = this.projects$.map(
    project => project.filter(
        item => item.id != id
    )
);
```